# Is it possible to have the screensaver activate after half a minute?

Tags: windows-8, screensaver

If I try to enter '0.5' into the "Wait:" field in screen saver settings, I get this error when I press the '.':

[image]

I want to activate the screensaver in half a minute.

The only solution I came up with was to write a program to monitor user input, and activate the screen saver after 30 seconds of no activity. If worse comes to worse, I can do that, however I prefer to simply change it in the windows system settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify this setting in the registry. In `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop` modify the `ScreenSaveTimeOut` value in seconds, then restart the computer or re-login. However, I have not tested whether a value under 60 will actually be kept after restart/login, so let me know if it doesn't work.